# "value error: Element locator did not match any element." while trying to locate a element

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot Framework with Selenium2Library for website tests automation. My HTML Value is

```
<select class="autoWidth m![Element Locator Error][1]inWidth" id="ctl00_ResultPanePlaceHolder_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_contentContainer_ddlLanguage" name="ctl00$ResultPanePlaceHolder$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$contentContainer$ddlLanguage">
<option value=![enter image description here][2]"1118">አማርኛ &lrm;(ኢትዮጵያ)&lrm;</option>
```

I am using cmd

```
Click Element   id=ctl00_ResultPanePlaceHolder_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_contentContainer_ddlLanguage
```

I am getting

```
value error: Element locator did not match any element.
```

How to fix this issue.

Comment: is your element inside an iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your element is inside an iframe. Look through the html to see if you see `<iframe ...>` before the element you are trying to click. If so, you first need to use [Select Frame](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Frame) before trying to click on the element.

Answer (score 1):

You should need to use id= as ID is one of the default attributes it looks for. Is it possible to see some more of the html code surrounding the element you are after?

Comment: using `id=` goes through a slightly different code path then if left off, and is at least arguably slightly more efficient.