# did not match any elements

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

*ValueError: Element locator* `'id=com.test.robot:id/et1'` *did not match any elements.*

Even though app source contains the above mentioned id

It is confusing !

Help required !

Comment: possible duplicate of ["value error: Element locator did not match any element." while trying to locate a element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645692/value-error-element-locator-did-not-match-any-element-while-trying-to-locate)

Comment: I have tried the solution but it is not working for me.

Comment: Why I am being down voted ? the question mentioned as duplicate its solution is not working for me..so I have asked separate question.Is it wrong ?

Comment: You are being down-voted because this question _is_ a duplicate of another question, and is of very low quality. You've added no details and shown no effort to do any research. There is absolutely no way we can duplicate your problem. How are we supposed to answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can locate the elements using variety of techniques.

One of them *xpath* and it'd work for sure under any circumstance

As we all know our UI is xml based one.
and *xpath* is the used the specify a particular node in the xml document for the element which we want to access

Here is the sample of *xpath* based locating

```
Click Element   xpath=/hierarchy[@rotation="0"]/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index="0"]/android.view.View[@index="0"]/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index="0"]/android.widget.ListView[@index="0"]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index="1"]/android.widget.TextView[@index="0"]
```

Comment: how to find xpath of particular element

Comment: Do you see any file called *log.html* in the directory ?

Comment: Yes I am seeing a log.html file

Comment: You would probably see the *xml of the app UI* in the place where error occurred in log.html

Comment: If you are not able to find then look in  *Appium Terminal* for *xml of app UI* it will echo the xml when the app screen is parsed

Comment: I got it ..how to find the xpath of the element ?

Comment: Visit the following site http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpath_generator.html then copy the *xml of app UI* and paste it in the *Xml field* and use browser find to search for the element for example .. if you want to locate *click me* button then search and click on the node in xml then *Xpath Results* will show the *Xpath* and use it as *locator* in test case

Comment: I am getting the same error

ValueError: Element locator did not match any elements.

Comment: You can try this *xpath tester* http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html first paste your xml in *Xml input* then paste your xpath in *Xpath expression* and click on *TEST XPATH* it should show the correct node that is it should locate the correct item..if anything is wrong then go back to the first url I have given and correctly click at the correct node then again copy the resultant xpath and paste it in the second url an confirm that locates correctly then use that test case.

Comment: I will check and tell you .